# Silverstripe 4.2.1 Live site don't detect public namespaced templates

Tags: templates, namespaces, themes, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

Everything is working on my local server but when I put the site online, everything works too except that the namespaced templates via **$Layout** are not detected so only the content of the 2 main Page.ss pages are visible.

Do you know how I could solve it?

I of course tried to dev/build, ?flush=1, ?flush=all etc but nothing works.

Here's my build structure:

```
    app
      _config
        **app.yml**
        **theme.yml**
      src
        **HomePage.php**
      templates
        **Page.ss**
        Include
        Layout
          **Page.ss**
        Silverstripe
          fefracaf
            Layout
              **HomePage.ss**
```

My namespace is:
**namespace SilverStripe\fefracaf;**

**mysite/app/src/HomePage.php**

```
<?php

namespace SilverStripe\fefracaf;

use Page;

class HomePage extends Page
{

}
```

**mysite/app/_config/app.yml**

```
---
Name: fefracaf
---
SilverStripe\Core\Manifest\ModuleManifest:
  project: app
```

**mysite/app/_config/theme.yml**

```
---
Name: mytheme
---
SilverStripe\View\SSViewer:
  themes:
    - '$public'
    - '$default'
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2):

It could be your folder name: `Silverstripe`. Your PHP namespace is `SilverStripe` - note that Linux systems are case sensitive, whereas local environments such as MacOS aren't.

Comment: @Grafka also you should avoid using SilverStripe as the namespace on your own classes. You could use your own organizations name for the top level ns.

Comment: It's solved, it was indeed because of the folder name "Silverstripe" in the namespace. Thanks for your help!